# how to create a view for duplicates?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have a list in SharePoint 2013

For example

- In Row 1: Column1 has 12 and Column2 has blackberry as values
- In Row 2: Column1 has 34 and Column2 has iphone as values
- In Row 3: Column1 has 12 and Cloumn2 has blackberry as values

Now I want to display rows which has duplicate values.
I want to create a view which shows only rows 1 and 3 which are duplicates.

Comment: As ListItems have no relationship with eachother you can't use data from multiple rows in a Filter. You could use ClientSideRendering code to preprocess a View and Hide items.

Comment: Create a view that groups by column 2? It won't get you fully there, but it will show "duplicates" in that they are grouped together.

Comment: If i use group by in view then it will show both duplicates and non duplicates. I want to see only duplicates in my view. Can this be done using custom view. If so the how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Nice challenge for *Out Of the Box thinking* where there are *no Out of the Box answers*

Programmers approach would we to use **Two Loops**

- One to loop all items and count the double ones
- And loop all items again to display an item or not

You can use Client Side Rendering for that; if you do all processing first you can built the HTML before it is displayed in the browser.

See: [Displaying list with only unique values in title column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162490/displaying-list-with-only-unique-values-in-title-column/162501#162501)

#### But..

you have to code some 30 lines of boilerplate code.. AND attach a JSlink to **every View* you want to use it.

**If you don't mind a flash (displayed content is erased)**

#### Out of the box with NO loops

.. well.. strictly speaking one loop... the original SharePoint code displaying a whole View

You can make each ListItem count itself and then check if its total count is > 1

**In A Calculated Column (set to datatype=Number)**

which executes some cute JavaScript(I haven't tested all browsers, works in Chrome and IE10)

Paste the Formula:

```
="<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
&"var C,v='count_"
&[Task Name]
&"',w=window,TR=this;while(TR.tagName!='TR'){TR=TR.parentNode}"
&"C=w.cnt=w.cnt||{};"
&"C[v]=C[v]||0;"
&"C[v]++;"
&"_spYield(function(){TR.style.display=['none','inherit'][C[v]==1?0:1]},1);"
&"}"">"
```

- Each item displays a blank IMG to trigger JavaScript code (the SCRIPT tag is disabled by Microsoft)
- You can then built a JavaScript variable **v** with the value you want to check doubles for

Since this code is always executed for every ListItem we need some special bookkeeping of Global variables

- we check if a Global variable (object) **cnt** exists, use it or declare it (once) as a new object
- we check if the **v**alue exists in the **cnt** object (a previous occurence) or set the counter to 0
- then always add 1 to the count

At this stage you could hide double values if the counter is >1 .. but you want the reverse, so it is essential we count all items first.

- _spYield (declared in SP.js, but you won't find any blogs or documentation) makes JavaScript execution **wait** (something not possible out of the box with JavaScript)

We need this wait/delay because IMGs are loaded async, thus this code as well and we want to make sure all ListItems are processed/counted.. a yield/Wait of 1 millisecond seems to be enough

So once all ListItems are counted they execute their own function

- the executed function sets the display based on the counter,

  - if the counter==1 we pick the 0th value in the text-array (hide)
  - otherwise the 1th value (leave double values displayed)