# Displaying list with only unique values in title column

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery

I have a requirement, an item should be added to a list, in the list web-part it should only display the title field value with unique values.

[image]

In the list as shown above, it should display developer team, architech team etc only once.

Is there any jquery to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for a script to run in a page that performs a scan to remove duplicate values in the list web part or you want a script that can be used in a content editor to display list items with unique title values ?

Comment: I need a script to run in a page that removes duplicate title column values of list items in the list view web part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  use **CSR** instead of jQuery to display duplicate items only once.

In order to do that you have to write some code in

```
OnPreRender: removeDuplicateByTitle
```

In the `OnPreRender` you have to remove duplicates from `ctx.ListData.Row`. `ctx.ListData.Row` is an array of objects.

[There are many ways](https://www.google.com.bd/search?q=find%20duplicate%20object%20by%20property%20javascript%20array&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enBD645BD645&oq=find&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59l3j69i60j69i59.3567j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) to remove duplicates. You can try [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq).

```
function removeDuplicateByTitle(ctx) {
      ctx.ListData.Row = _.uniq(ctx.ListData.Row, 'Title');
    }
```

**Prerequisite**

> Add lodash script reference in your master page or in a particular
>   page. Download it from [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/lodash.js/)

You can use [Cisar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en) for CSR. Find full code in [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/duwopu/edit?html,js,output)

**View before applying JSLink**

[image]

**View after applying JSLink**

[image]

See [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162224/csr-dynamic-auto-populate-fields-based-on-lookup-column-item/162286#162286) post by [Danny Engelman](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/32871/danny-engelman) for using **Cisar**

Comment: thanks, but how I have to apply this code in SharePoint site.

Comment: As you say.. It could be bad.. You are doing a ``for`` loop inside a ``forEach`` with the same array... So for a List with n items **this code is looping n * n times** (at worst)

Comment: Yeah I know ...... Trying to fix that and other problem.  You can suggest something! @DannyEngelman

Comment: See my updates now @vikashkumar

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the group-by function in your view?
It's not what you aksed for, but maybe it is enough

Go to your list

Click on the thre dots and choose "modify view"

Scroll down to "Group by"

Choose the Column you want to group by (probably "Title" in your case)

Answer (score 2):

*As Atish asked for a suggestion in his other answer...*

This **OnPostRender** function filters out the duplicates after the list is displayed.

```
       var allValues=[];
       ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(item){
         var duplicateCheck=item.Title,
             TR=document.getElementById(GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx,item));
         if(allValues.indexOf(duplicateCheck)>-1) TR.style.display='none';
         allValues.push(duplicateCheck);
       });
```

- This code displays the whole List, then hides duplicates.
  It is better to use either the `OnPreRender` or `Item` template function to not display duplicates at all.

#### Update #1

As stated in the comments, you probably want this in the `OnPostRender` function
because **you want your users to see what the Duplicates are**

I had to replicate some licensed code to add a Toggle button.
The licensed code is complete OOP and adds a Duplicate filter to all Columns.

This will get you started:

```
OnPostRender : function () {
    var check = 'Title', //name of Item field to check for duplicates
    all = [], //holds all values
    duplicates = [], //holds all duplicate TR elements, EXCLUDING the first value
    duplicatesShown = true,//will be reset on first init
    button = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    function addToggleButton() {
        button.onclick = function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            duplicatesShown = !duplicatesShown;
            duplicates.forEach(function (TR) {
                TR.style.display = duplicatesShown ? 'inherit' : 'none';
            });
            button.innerHTML = (duplicatesShown ? 'Hide' : 'Show') + ' Duplicates';
        };
        document.getElementById('CSRListViewControlDivWPQ2').appendChild(button);
    };
    ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function (item) {
        if (all.indexOf(item[check]) > -1) {
            var TR = document.getElementById(GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, item));
            TR.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
            duplicates.push(TR);
        }
        all.push(item[check]);
    });
    addToggleButton();
    button.click();
}
```

- *I am still learning every day and copy/paste/pick apart examples as well*
  Just realised yesterday all examples out there declare the `ctx` variable,
  which is totally not required as `ctx` is a Global object and in JS objects are passed by reference.
  I tried to stick that TR reference on the `item` but that doesn't work.. Seems SharePoint keeps it as a an immutable object... *ah well.. more to investigate*
- If you want to highlight all duplicate values you have to add another loop for all items AFTER the first initialisation
  *that is probably why Atish had a loop IN a loop in his original code*

ICSR

Comment: In `OnPreRender`, Still, I can not think anything else **n*n** looping. I asked you to suggest something about it. Anyway, your answer is also cool.

Comment: We used ``OnPostRender`` so the duplicate items are actually there. Because... **we also added a button that Shows/Hides the duplicates**.. I can't copy that full code because it is licensed; will have to replicate it and add it to my post... isn't that difficult.

Comment: yeah please share if possible after replication.

Comment: In last update, I have replaced loop IN a loop by `_.uniq`. But I guess, there is also **n*n** inside `_.uniq`.

Answer (score 2):

You will be required to follow a 2 stepped approach in order to get unique values from the List.

The stages would be:

1. Getting all list items from the List
2. Using LINQ to get unique values from ListItemCollection.

Use the code given below:

```
//1 Execute query against SP Linq provider   
string keyCol = "SPFieldName";
CamlQuery keyColumnValuesQuery = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
ListItemCollection keyColumnValues = srcDocLib.GetItems(keyColumnValuesQuery);
spContext.Load(keyColumnValues, items => items.Include(item => item[keyCol]), items => items.OrderBy(item => item[keyCol]));
spContext.ExecuteQuery();
//2. Transform LiItemCollection to a List and perform Distinct operation 
var uniqueKeyColumnValues = keyColumnValues.ToList().Select(i => i[keyCol]).Distinct();
```

Comment: **OP** asked for client side code not server side code