# alert based view when duplicates are detected

Tags: list-view, alert

Is it possible to create an alert based view if 2 records with the same field value are found in the a SharePoint list?

Comment: Can you please add more details to this question, it is not very clear what your requirement is?

Comment: See [this for CSR approach](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162490/displaying-list-with-only-unique-values-in-title-column/162501#162501)  and [this for a Calculated Column Trick](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/159043/how-to-create-a-view-for-duplicates)

Comment: I dont need necessarily a view. In fact what I need is a mechanism that will alert me if the field "form code" has another duplicate in the list.